# Неправильный вывод символов в цикле

Tags: c++

Имеется цикл for, внутри которого рандомно выбирается символ из массива и выводится в консоль. По окончании программы оказывается, что выводится только последний выбранный символ(при этом при пошаговом просмотре программы выводятся все 5 символов!!!)
В чём проблема и как её можно исправить?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    srand(time(0));
    symb = uncoded[rand() % (len + 1)];
    cout << '|' << setw(8) << right << symb << '|';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Немного не так интерпретируете результат - у вас получается одно и то же случайное число.

`srand()` выполняйте **один раз**, например, в начале программы.

При пошаговом просмотре время, которым инициализируется srand, меняется существенно, и стартовые значения последовательности случайных чисел будут разные